# Upgrading CiviHR to 1.6.8

Tags: civihr

Does anyone have clear instructions on how to upgrade CiviHR? The ones included on GitHub are for drupal.  I tried to do it manually by copying over the CiviHR folder with 1.6.8 but it just broke CiviCRM altogether.  I don't have access to drush or anything like that, so I can only copy it and then run the updates manually in extensions manager in CiviCRM.

Answer (score 0):

CiviHR isn't a normal extension that you can install on a general purpose CiviCRM installation.  It is intended to be run as a dedicated CiviHR system and is only supported on Drupal.

There is a new site at https://civihr.org/ and wiki at https://civihr.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CIV/Welcome

There is a lot of development activity ongoing and some of the docs are lagging behind.  I think they are still offering free hosting if you join the Early Adopters program and meet certain requirements.